# how to include css file in view - laravel

Tags: css, laravel-5

I am new to laravel and trying to include a css file in my view. The css file is located in

> resources\assets\css\style.css

I am trying to include it with the following command:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/style.css') }}">
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The URL::asset has the base directory linked to public folder. So in your above code you are referencing to `/public/assets/css/style.css`.

Move your files to public directory and every thing should work as expected.

Comment: I would also recommend looking into gulp. Gulp will compile all the scss files in your assets/css directory to a single css file in your public folder. This link should be able to help you: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir#sass

Answer (score 0):

**my custom css file is in the `/public/assets/css/style.css`**

so i can use this syntax..,

```
  <link href="{{ asset('css/custom.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```